# Grant select on any table/view on the schema

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle if I am creating user/schema FOO then creating bunch of tables on schema FOO,

Is there a way I can give User FOO grant select on all tables/views before tables/views are created?
Or I will have to do it only after the tables/views are created?

```
CREATE USER FOO ....
/
*** GRANT SELECT TO USER FOO ON ANY TABLE/VIEW CREATED
/
CREATE TABLE 1    ...
/
CREATE TABLE ...   ...
/
CREATE TABLE N     ...
/
```

Comment: The user `foo` will always be able to query objects in the `foo` schema.  `foo` owns those objects so `foo` can drop them, alter them, query them, etc.  Do you possibly mean that you want a user `bar` to have access to all the objects in the `foo` schema?

Comment: Good catch - I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but you can give `select` (or any other) privilege on all the tables of a schema with dynamic sql:

```
begin
  for i in (
            select 'grant select on ' || table_name || ' to USER2' as stm
            from dba_tables
            where owner = 'USER1'
            )
  loop
    execute immediate i.stm;
  end loop;
end;
```

This is slighty different from what you asked, given that you only can execute this after that you have created all the tables; however, it's a simple piece of SQL that you can run after every table creation to be sure that you user is completely granted.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a `grant select on <schema_name> to <user_name>`. Today such a thing does not exist. There is an open request/user poll on this issue at OTN (Oracle Technology Network), which is currently active:

https://community.oracle.com/ideas/2333

In the same place you will find ideas for a workaround if needed.

Comment: I remember that there was a trick to create a role, and assign the user to the role then create the tables, but I don't remember how

Comment: You can create a role to simplify your life, but you still can't grant select on a schema to the role. You will still grant table access after the fact, but to just one role rather than to individual users.